# replace multiple strings in dataframe (Python / Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below including in a script and I'm sure there must be a better way to code this. Perhaps referring to two lists, reducing the number of lines. This is two different data frames but the replaced text is the same across both, so again could both df be referenced in the same line?

```
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Monday', 'Mon', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Tuesday', 'Tue', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Wednesday', 'Wed', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Thursday', 'Thu', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Friday', 'Fri', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Saturday', 'Sat', regex=True)
df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace('Sunday', 'Sun', regex=True)

df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Monday', 'Mon', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Tuesday', 'Tue', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Wednesday', 'Wed', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Thursday', 'Thu', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Friday', 'Fri', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Saturday', 'Sat', regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace('Sunday', 'Sun', regex=True)
```

Matt

Comment: can you provide an example of the DataFrame?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? That is, do you need to replace substrings, or are you replacing whole values with whole values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict containing the changes and then use the `replace` method you already used:

```
changes = {'Monday' : 'Mon',
           'Tuesday': 'Tue',
           'Wednesday': 'Wed',
           'Thursday': 'Thu',
           'Friday': 'Fri',
           'Saturday': 'Sat',
           'Sunday': 'Sun'}

df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace(changes, regex=True)
df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace(changes, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

make use of the map

If you post the data, it'll be easier to present the solution. but, here is the idea

```
df_Final_hours[COLUMN_NAME].map(
    {'Monday':'Mon',
     'Tuesday':'Tue',
     'Wednesday': 'Wed',
     'Thursday' : 'Thu',
     'Friday' : 'Fri',
     'Saturday' : 'Sat',
     'Sunday' : 'Sun'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dictionary like this:

```
weekAbrvs= {
  "Monday": "Mon",
  "Tuesday": "Tues",
  "Wednesday": "Wed"
}
```

then you can do one for loop that changes/sets both `df_Final_hours` and `df_Final_traffic`

so something like this:

```
for key,value in weekAbrvs.items():
  df_Final_hours = df_Final_hours.replace(key, value, regex=True)
  df_Final_traffic = df_Final_traffic.replace(key, value, regex=True)
```

check this out: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can import calendar create a dictionary then use replace with regex=True:

```
import calendar
d = dict(zip(calendar.day_name, calendar.day_abbr))
df.replace(d, regex=True)
```